# Flutter Firestore getting incomplete array

Tags: flutter, dart, google-cloud-firestore

I'm trying to fetch an array of strings I have saved on my database but I'm getting the array back with missing values, only the first value is shown inside of it. Here's the structure of my database:

**Path: /users/uid/services**  <-- this is the array

[image]

**Path: /services/uid** <--service document

[image]

The code I'm using to retrieve the users is:

```
_getWorkers() async {
    var query = await Firestore.instance.collection('users').where('services', arrayContains: widget.category['uid']).getDocuments();

    query.documents.forEach((doc) {
      workers.add(doc.data);
      List<String> values = List.from(doc.data['services']);
      print('services:' + values.toString());
    });

    var test = await Firestore.instance.collection('users').document('PtBD2EMSTodvlx6WHUx8QOHHLNA2').get();

    print('actual services:' + test['services'].toString());
}
```

Both `query` and `test` get data back, but the `services` array only contains the first value.

Comment: In your path you are using `/user/uid/services` in your request you are requesting the collection for `users` should this not be the same? ex user or users

Comment: Edited the question, the path is indeed `/users/uid/services`

Answer (score 0):

Its difficult to answer without actually seeing the entire DB structure. But still on the outset i can see only one error with your code.
When you are trying to execute the `where()` call, try adding the `snapshots` to retrieve all relevant data.

Since `await` is also used, it is much better to call the `listen()` on it and then read the values to be added to the `worker`

Try using this below code in place of your first line.

```
await Firestore.instance.collection('users').where('services', arrayContains: widget.category['uid']).snapshots().listen((query)=>query.documents.forEach((doc)=>print(doc.data['services'])));
```

Answer (score 0):

For some reason Firebase wasn't returning the updated array. Tested it again today and it worked with the same code. Sorry for bothering, thanks for the help anyways.